# AMSlideMenu crash: Receiver (<MenuViewController: 0x10db0da10>) has no segue with identifier 'rightMenu'

Tags: ios, objective-c, amslidemenu

I know there is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619927/ios-amslidemenu-receiver-mainvc-0x8f92a90-has-no-segue-with-identifier-rig) about this, but the answer provided did not solve my problem.

For start, I had 3 three segues pointing to 3 different view controllers and coming from the `AMSlideMenuLeftTableViewController` class. The first segue and view controller that I created was the view that appeared as the first view (the one that shows when the app loads).

However, since I deleted that first view my app crashes immediately after opening it up.

This is the crash log:

```
2014-09-02 17:17:56.200 App[3174:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<MenuViewController>: 0x10db0da10>) has no segue with identifier 'rightMenu''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100433495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001030f499e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   UIKit                               0x0000000101d99515 -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0
3   App                        0x000000010002d67f -[AMSlideMenuMainViewController setup] + 1071
4   App                        0x000000010002aae1 -[AMSlideMenuMainViewController viewDidLoad] + 353
5   App                        0x00000001000915e6 -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] + 54
6   UIKit                               0x0000000101d9759e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 562
7   UIKit                               0x0000000101d97777 -[UIViewController view] + 29
8   UIKit                               0x00000001020a22e2 -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 390
9   UIKit                               0x0000000101cddffa -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1109
10  UIKit                               0x0000000101cddb9f -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 36
11  UIKit                               0x0000000101cddaef -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 101
12  UIKit                               0x0000000101cdcdfe -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 377
13  UIKit                               0x0000000101d9b70a -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 147
14  UIKit                               0x0000000101cd7b1b -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 490
15  UIKit                               0x0000000101cd7c70 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
16  UIKit                               0x0000000101ce0ffa -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 51
17  UIKit                               0x0000000101c9cc98 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1788
18  UIKit                               0x0000000101ca0a0c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 660
19  UIKit                               0x0000000101cb1d4c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3189
20  UIKit                               0x0000000101cb2216 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79
21  UIKit                               0x0000000101ca2086 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 578
22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000104eff71a _PurpleEventCallback + 762
23  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000104eff1e1 PurpleEventCallback + 35
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001003b5679 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001003b544e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001003de903 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001003ddd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
28  UIKit                               0x0000000101ca02e1 -[UIApplication _run] + 609
29  UIKit                               0x0000000101ca1e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
30  App                        0x0000000100076503 main + 115
31  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000103ddd5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I think the problem is that the app is trying to display the view I deleted as the main view but it isn't there. The fact is that I have not found any reference to that old view I deleted.

Comment: Your `AMSlideMenuMainViewController.setup()` is calling the segue with the `rootMenu` identifier.

Comment: @NRitH - What do mean? I never set ``rootMenu`` as an identifier.

Comment: I meant `rightMenu`.

Comment: @NRitH -  But I don't have a right menu. Before, everything was working and still I did not use right menu.

Comment: @alvarolopez use LGSideMenu, because i already used it, so if you stuck any point i will help you

Comment: @alvarolopez use LGSideMenu, because i already used it, so if you stuck any point i will help you

Answer (score 2):

If `AMSlideMenu` catches an exception when trying to create `LeftMenu`, it then tries to create `RightMenu` (I don't understand why, but is true).

In my case the left menu `firstSegue` pointed to a 'wrong view', because it was a simple view controller, not a navigation controller. I changed the view controller to a navigation controller (that points to my original view controller), and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the AMSlideMenuWithoutStoryboard-Prefix.pch file settings to the PCH file from your project.