# Problems with AMSlideMenu without storyboard Reciever has no segue with identifier 'rightMenu'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, amslidemenu

This might have been posted before and believe me we tried searching and tried the solutions but it didn't help solving our problem (I will list what we found here on StackOverflow).

1. We do have a sample project in Xcode 9 and using Objective C. Composed of XIB (we don't use storyboards so please don't answer that is related with storyboards or swift). The AMSlideMenu was installed using PODS

[image: xcode version]

2. Our project structure looks like this:

[image: XCode Project Structure]

AppDelegate will vcMain and a button will launch vcClientMain. vcClientMain is a AMSlideMenuMainViewController and should have the left and right slide menus.

**AppDelegate:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    vcMain *mainView = [[vcMain alloc] initWithNibName:@"vcMain" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = mainView;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    return YES;
}
```

**vcMain client button clicked:**

```
- (IBAction)btnClientClicked:(id)sender {
    vcClientMain *mainView = [[vcClientMain alloc] initWithNibName:@"vcClientMain" bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:mainView animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

3. The prefix.pch file contains the code below which we copied from withoutstoryboad sampl of AMSSlideMenu (included it on both the actual project and the pods project)

   ```
   #import <Availability.h>

   #ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
   #warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and             later."
   #endif

   #define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
   #define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
   #define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
   #define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
   #define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)

   #define AMSlideMenuWithoutStoryboards

   #ifdef __OBJC__
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #endif
   ```
4. We are receiving this error when the Client button is clicked

```
    2018-01-14 03:44:17.102821+0800 Travellogger[5275:1112453] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'rightMenu''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001064a312b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a957f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010822e3d0 -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0
    3   Travellogger                        0x00000001060a36f7 -[AMSlideMenuMainViewController setup] + 1063
    4   Travellogger                        0x00000001060a09a3 -[AMSlideMenuMainViewController viewDidLoad] + 387
    5   Travellogger                        0x000000010609e7d3 -[vcClientMain viewDidLoad] + 275
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010822b46c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1235
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010822b8b9 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000108cc4441 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 89
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001081f82a3 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 133
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010823eb67 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3808
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001082419a9 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 99
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000108242079 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 532
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000108241908 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 181
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000108241c67 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 159
    15  Travellogger                        0x000000010609b8f8 -[vcMain btnClientClicked:] + 120
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000108084972 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000108203c3c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000108203f59 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000108202981 -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 282
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001080fa562 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2130
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001080fbf2a -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010809f365 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001089eba1d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001089ee672 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106446101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001064e5f71 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010642aa19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106429fff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106429889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010dfee9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    31  UIKit                               0x00000001080835d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    32  Travellogger                        0x000000010609e69f main + 111
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b721d81 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

5. Here are some of the stuff that we researched on Stackoverflow but unfortunately didn't do the work:

[iOS AMSlideMenu Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'rightMenu''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619927/ios-amslidemenu-receiver-mainvc-0x8f92a90-has-no-segue-with-identifier-rig)

[AMSlideMenu crash: Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'rightMenu'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627167/amslidemenu-crash-receiver-menuviewcontroller-0x10db0da10-has-no-segue-wit/28797506)

6. The [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgcRc7D3qJw) doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy to integrate and smooth slide menu

[https://github.com/beingbarath/BMSlideMenu](http://BMSlideMenu)

[image]

Integration of SWRevealViewController. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes. But this is the swift tutorial. You don't need to add a bridge header.

Comment: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController
You will get a better idea here